# CommonJs: where to put initialization code?

Tags: node.js, commonjs

Learning CommonJS and trying out figure where to put code that initializes private variables.  In C# or Java, I would use a constructor, but I haven't been able to figure out how/where to achieve this with CommonJs.

Here's some code to illustrate my requirement:

```
var _myPrivateVariable;

var CoolModule = {
{
    foo: function(task) {
    //do something that relies on _myPrivateVariable having been properly initialized

    },
    bar: function(task) {
    //do something that relies on _myPrivateVariable having been properly initialized

    },

module.exports = CoolModule
```

Comment: You don't have any classes there, so why not just initialize it on the same line you define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time you first use `require('./CoolModule')`, node run your module's code and cache it.

So your CoolModule just like a `singleton`.

JavaScript doesn't have Java-like class, it can use function constructor to initialize.

```
var _myPrivateVariable;

// function constructor
function CoolModule(args) {


}

CoolModule.prototype.foo = function(task) {

};
CoolModule.prototype.bar = function(task) {

};

module.exports = CoolModule;
```

And then

```
var CoolModule = require('./CoolModule');
var cool = new CoolModule(args);

cool.foo //...
cool.bar //...
```